# Indicator variable syntax

Tags: probability-distributions

Are these syntax equivalent?

$$f(x,\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}I_{(0,+\infty)}(x),\ \lambda > 0$$

$$f(x,\lambda) = \left \{
    \begin{array}{cl}
        \lambda e^{-\lambda x} & x \gt 0 \\
        0 & \text{Otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right .$$

Comment: Whops, mistake corrected.

Comment: Yes. I generally use the former notation as it is more concise.